Error logs is Not printing int the /var/log/apache2/logs
My Webapplication is running in the docker container and apache2 is not in docker and running in host im using proxy and docker ip to redirect the request to docker it is working fine but the if my application gives any error it is not printing in the error logs in /var/log
Below is the error:
[Tue Sep 10 14:20:52.619931 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 390208:tid 140061567874816] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 183.*.*.*:Port] AH01084: pass request body failed to 172.*.*.*:port (172.*.*.*), referer: https://web.*/ [Tue Sep 10 14:20:52.620084 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 390208:tid 140061567874816] [client 183.*.*.*:Port] AH01097: pass request body failed to 172.*.*.*:port (172.*.*.*) from 183.82.24.226 (), referer: https://web.*/
Below is the configuration of apache2:
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName web
ServerAlias web

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
# Forward requests to Docker container
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyTimeout 120
ProxyBadHeader Ignore
ProxyIOBufferSize 65536
ProxyPass / http://172.1*.*.*:port/
ProxyPassReverse / http://172.1172.1*.*.*:port/

SSLEngine on
SSLUseStapling on
#SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors on
#SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5

SSLProtocol         all -SSLv3 -SSLv2 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite      ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256

SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression      off
SSLSessionTickets   off
SSLCertificateFile      /*/*/*/*/*/*/*
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /*/*/*/*/*/*/*

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>


